# Update records in the same table searching for common records in another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

First of all apologize for the long title but I couldn't find another appropriate title
for the request I am going to explain:
In the db there are 3 tables, one providing headers for documents, one for the related details,
and the third one for the "links" between different kind of documents (for example, if there's
a delivery note followed by an invoice, generated usually at the end of the month, grouping all
the delivery notes of the same month).
Tables and fields involved are called:

```
    + DO11_DOCTESTATA  (for the headers)
     - DO11_DOCUM_MG36 Gives the type of the document stored (I need to retrieve data from 'FOR-FATRIEPDDT' and insert into 'FOR-DDT'
     - DO11_NUMDOC Contains the number of the document, needed to search WHERE do11_numdoc = equals the same number in DO33_DOCCORPORIF

    + DO30_DOCCORPO    (for the details)
     - DO30_PREZZO1    Contains the unity price, when I have a match between do11_numdoc = do33_doccorporif.do33_numnsdoc, I update this field)
     - DO30_PREZZO1IVA Same as before, but price added with VAT
     - DO30_IMPORTO    Price * Quantity
     - ...
     - ...

    + DO33_DOCCORPORIF (for the links)
     - DO33_NUMNSDOC  Which contains the number of the relative delivery note that I need to compare to DO11_DOCTESTATA.DO11_NUMDOC to find a match
```

My request is to update some fields in DO30_DOCCORPO because I need to update prices from invoices
and putting the same values in the corresponding delivery note, by matching the number found in DO11_DOCTESTATA.DO11_NUMDOC with the same field
in DO33_DOCCORPORIF.DO33_NUMNSDOC

When a match is found, I need to update fields in DO30_DOCCORPO, WHERE DO11_DOCTESTATA = 'FOR-DDT' meaning that I'm updating data only when
the document type is a delivery note ('FOR-DDT').

I have managed to create the SELECT query that gives me the data I need to update, but I am unable to "transform" this query into an UPDATE because
I lack of experience in SQL language. This is the SELECT query

```
SELECT do11_doctestata.do11_docum_mg36, 
   do11_doctestata.do11_datadoc, 
   do11_doctestata.do11_numdoc, 
   do11_doctestata.do11_sezdoc, 
   do33_doccorporif.do33_numnsdoc, 
   do30_doccorpo.do30_codart_mg66, 
   do30_doccorpo.do30_qta1, 
   do30_doccorpo.do30_prezzo1, 
   do30_doccorpo.do30_prezzo1iva, 
   do30_doccorpo.do30_importo, 
   do30_doccorpo.do30_importoiva, 
   do30_doccorpo.do30_impnetscp 
FROM   do11_doctestata 
   INNER JOIN do33_doccorporif 
           ON do11_doctestata.do11_numdoc = do33_doccorporif.do33_numnsdoc 
   INNER JOIN do30_doccorpo 
           ON do11_doctestata.do11_ditta_cg18 = 
              do30_doccorpo.do30_ditta_cg18 
              AND do11_doctestata.do11_numreg_co99 = 
                  do30_doccorpo.do30_numreg_co99 
WHERE  ( do11_doctestata.do11_docum_mg36 = 'FOR-DDT' )
```

and [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwRZ5fba7iLXUXQzWVlLY3BDQTA) is a sample of the results. The highlighted rows are
typical rows that I need to update, BUT ONLY when numbers of DO11_NUMDOC AND DO33_NUMNSDOC match

Edit: still stuck on this issue
Edit: using the folllowing code:

```
MERGE INTO DO30_DOCCORPO A
    USING DO30_DOCCORPO_TEMP B
        ON A.DO30_PROGRIGA = B.DO30_PROGRIGA
        AND A.DO30_NUMREG_CO99 = B.DO30_NUMREG_CO99
        AND A.DO30_DITTA_CG18 = B.DO30_DITTA_CG18
        AND A.DO30_CAUSMAG_MG51 = '9999'
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
        SET DO30_PREZZO1 = B.DO30_PREZZO1,
            DO30_PREZZO1IVA = B.DO30_PREZZO1IVA,
            DO30_IMPORTO = B.DO30_IMPORTO,
            DO30_IMPORTOIVA = B.DO30_IMPORTOIVA,
            DO30_IMPNETSCP = B.DO30_IMPNETSCP;
```

I managed to get the Management Studio do something. In fact, after executing, it says, "Rows affected: 1" but there's still one issue: the row

```
AND A.DO30_CAUSMAG_MG51 = '9999' should update WHERE DO30_CAUSMAG_MG51 = '100'
```

so it should read when values is '9999' but update rows where the same column has '100' as value

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
UPDATE DO30_DOCCORPO
SET  DO30_DOCCORPO.do30_importo=... 
    , ...
FROM   do11_doctestata 
   INNER JOIN do33_doccorporif 
           ON do11_doctestata.do11_numdoc = do33_doccorporif.do33_numnsdoc 
   INNER JOIN do30_doccorpo 
           ON do11_doctestata.do11_ditta_cg18 = 
              do30_doccorpo.do30_ditta_cg18 
          AND do11_doctestata.do11_numreg_co99 =do30_doccorpo.do30_numreg_co99 
WHERE  ( do11_doctestata.do11_docum_mg36 = 'FOR-DDT' )
```

Edit after comment: How about now?

Comment: No, the update should work on DO30_DOCCORPO. It's there that there are the records lke DO30_PREZZO1, and so on that should be updtated

Comment: I edited my answer after your comment. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Should be ok, but as a last request, what should I put in the SET part? SET DO30_DOCCORPO.DO30_IMPORTO = ???  How could I retrieve the price to set?

Comment: The new (updated) values. You can even use the values from another table i.e. `SET DO30_DOCCORPO.DO30_IMPORTO = do11_doctestata.DO11_IMPORTO`

Comment: The updated values (the prices) are in the same table, DO30_DOCCORPO...if they were in another table I shouldn't had no problems but, as the title of my question says, it's: how do I update data when data to update TO and data to update FROM are in the same table, and the key to choose wich records should I update is stored in two more tables (DO11_DOCTESTATA.DO11_NUMDOC = DO33_DOCCORPORIF.DO33_NUMNSDOC)

Comment: Maybe one solution could be using temporary tables, but how to use them it is unknown for me